# No space in given name - Malaysia Airlines

Tags: air-travel, tickets, malaysia-airlines

On my passport there is space in my given name. It disappeared in my flight ticket. Will I be refused check in or boarding, or during immigration border control on London Heathrow airport or at Malaysia airports?

Eg:

1. Passport:

   - First Name: Mei Lin
   - LastName: Foo
2. Flight ticket:

   - First Name: Meilin
   - LastName: Foo

Comment: No, it is not a problem at all. Essentially there is no concept of space for many (if not most) ticketing systems. I'd answer but I think there is a comprehensive duplicate somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

The matching algorithms used are very broad — as they would have to be, to avoid causing chaos.

In the specific case of matching your reservation to your passport, I would not worry about that at all.  The airline will give the PAX manifest (which comes from the ticket info) to Immigration but if they cannot match an entry from the passports they scan, that is a problem for *them*, which will occur after you are admitted and so have no effect on you at all.